# error while pressing any button \ 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: java

App in android vm stops suddenly.
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

**Help please.
android studio error**
**error:**

> 2021-01-08 00:58:49.288 9583-9583/com.example.simplecalculator
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.simplecalculator, PID: 9583
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable
> android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
> at com.example.simplecalculator.MainActivity.sum(MainActivity.java:33)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
> at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
> 2021-01-08 00:58:49.336 9583-9583/com.example.simplecalculator
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9583 SIG: 9

**adding my code also.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num1Text;
    EditText num2Text;
    TextView ResText;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText num1Text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1Text);
        EditText num2Text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2Text);
        TextView ResText =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResText);

    }


    public void sum(View view) {

        if(num1Text.getText().toString().matches("") || num2Text.getText().toString().matches("")){
            ResText.setText("Enter number");
        }
        else{
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText().toString());
            result = num1 + num2;
            ResText.setText("Result = " + result);
        }

    }

    public void deduct(View view) {
        if(num1Text.getText().toString().matches("") || num2Text.getText().toString().matches("")){
            ResText.setText("Enter number");
        }
        else {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText().toString());
            result = (num1 - num2);
            ResText.setText("Result = " + result);
        }

    }

    public void multiply(View view) {
        if(num1Text.getText().toString().matches("") || num2Text.getText().toString().matches("")){
            ResText.setText("Enter number");
        }
        else {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText().toString());
            result = num1 * num2;
            ResText.setText("Result = " + result);
        }

    }

    public void divide(View view) {
        if(num1Text.getText().toString().matches("") || num2Text.getText().toString().matches("")){
            ResText.setText("Enter number");
        }
        else {
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Text.getText().toString());
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Text.getText().toString());
            result = num1 / num2;
            ResText.setText("Result = " + result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the Object name inside the `onCreate()` when you initialize the `EditText`? It appears as if you're defining these variables twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the `EditText` and `TextView` fields correctly.

What your code is actually doing is using findViewById to get the values, *and then assigning them to local variables* rather than to the appropriate fields.

Change

```
    EditText num1Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1Text);
    EditText num2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2Text);
    TextView ResText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResText);
```

to

```
    num1Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1Text);
    num2Text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2Text);
    ResText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ResText);
```

It is worth noting that there are other bugs.  For example, you are not dealing with the case where the user enters a non-numeric value in one of the text boxes.  This will result in an exception when you try to turn the text into a number.